# Apache SSL reverse proxy breaks Liferay Authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, liferay

I have Apache 2.2. installed with SSL.  It is running as a reverse proxy based on a question I asked and was answered here: [Apache SSL reverse proxy for multiple servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/450955/apache-ssl-reverse-proxy-for-multiple-servers) What I discovered, however, is that the "sign in" prompt in Liferay no longer will authenticate.  In FF I am given a security warning but my userid and password does not work.  In other browsers, no security warning is given, but the authentication fails.  Yet, if I use the IP address in the ProxyPass directives to go to the web page and then sign in, all is well.  I assumed that Apache is passing all traffic back to the server unencrypted.

So, I am guessing that the data is getting mangled (somehow) in the ProxyPass directives so that Liferay cannot read the data.  Is there another directive I need to add to the VirtualHost entry so that the data is passed unencrypted (or unmangled) to Liferay?

So, based on the post referenced above, when I go to http://www.mydomain.com I am redirected to https://www.mydomain.com which is properly hitting the `http://192.168.20.200` server but the authentication fails.  If I go directly to `http://192.168.20.200` I can authenticate just fine.  So somewhere in the https:// to http:// translation, something is getting hammered (I think).

Did I miss something in the VirtualHost directive that is messing up the authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I think for this one, I would recommened trying out:

web.server.protocol=https

in the portal-ext.properties.

Comment: I don't know for sure if this took care of the issue but I did add the directive and it is now working.  Thanks.