# Getting HAPROXY to redirect http to https in users browser session

Tags: https, haproxy, rhel5

We are currently using a Internet cloud provider to host our SaaS platform. The platform consists of a Firewall -> Cloud Provider SLB ->  -> Apache Web Server ->  HAPROXY SLB -> Liferay Platform

We have had to use HAPROXY because of an issue with the cloud providers SLB that meant we were unable to use it for load balancing the Liferay platform applications.

I have implemented HAPROXY in our secure tier and that seems to do the trick of load balancing the requests quite adequately.

However during testing we encountered a functional issue whereby selecting a sub-menu from the web portal resulted in the application hanging, using an http analyser we saw that the request being passed back to the users browser was in http, from discussing this with the software vendor it transpires that the Liferay application has some hard-coded http links, and that other customers have worked around this by using physical NLB's such as F5 and redirecting the http traffic to https.

The entry in the HAPROXY logs reads:

```
haproxy[2717]: haproxy[2717]: <Apache Web Agent>:37957 [11/Apr/2013:08:07:00.128] http-uapi uapi/<ServerName> 0/0/0/9/10 200 4912 - - ---- 4/2/1/2/0 0/0 "GET /servicedesk/controller?docommand=renderradform&!key=esd_sfb001_frm_feedback_forms_list&isportalintegratedmode=true&USR=joe.bloggs%40gmail.com&_dc=1365667773097&redirecturl=controller%3Fdocommand%3Drenderbody%26%21key%3DESD_SFB001_FRM_FEEDBACK_FORMS_LIST%26isportalintegratedmode%3Dtrue&sso_token=ALiYv2UqzLsAhSw1ZchRDlCHlq44Bhj9&ONERROR=%2Fweb%2Fjsp%2Fapps%2Fportal-integration-error.jsp&itype=login&slicetoken=NW51O%242aRo%2C_Zz%2476P_9DTtnFmz6%28bhk&AUTOFORWARDURL=controller%3Fdocommand%3Drenderbody%26%21key%3DESD_SFB001_FRM_FEEDBACK_FORMS_LIST%26isportalintegratedmode%3Dtrue&LOGINPAGE=https%3A%2F%2F<FQDN of Web Portal>%2Fweb%2F4732cf01-82c3-4bc5-b6c9-552253e672cf%2Fworkflow-tools&appid=1&!uid=1&!redownloadToken=7.0.3.1.1363611301.0&userlocale=en_US&!datechanged=2012-05-18%2015:05:31.38 HTTP/1.1"
:37957 [11/Apr/2013:08:07:00.128] http-uapi uapi/<ServerName> 0/0/0/9/10 200 4912 - - ---- 4/2/1/2/0 0/0 "GET /servicedesk/controller?docommand=renderradform&!key=esd_sfb001_frm_feedback_forms_list&isportalintegratedmode=true&USR=joe.bloggs%40gmail.com&_dc=1365667773097&redirecturl=controller%3Fdocommand%3Drenderbody%26%21key%3DESD_SFB001_FRM_FEEDBACK_FORMS_LIST%26isportalintegratedmode%3Dtrue&sso_token=ALiYv2UqzLsAhSw1ZchRDlCHlq44Bhj9&ONERROR=%2Fweb%2Fjsp%2Fapps%2Fportal-integration-error.jsp&itype=login&slicetoken=NW51O%242aRo%2C_Zz%2476P_9DTtnFmz6%28bhk&AUTOFORWARDURL=controller%3Fdocommand%3Drenderbody%26%21key%3DESD_SFB001_FRM_FEEDBACK_FORMS_LIST%26isportalintegratedmode%3Dtrue&LOGINPAGE=https%3A%2F%2F<FQDN of Web Portal>%2Fweb%2F4732cf01-82c3-4bc5-b6c9-552253e672cf%2Fworkflow-tools&appid=1&!uid=1&!redownloadToken=7.0.3.1.1363611301.0&userlocale=en_US&!datechanged=2012-05-18%2015:05:31.38 HTTP/1.1"
```

The corresponding HTTP browser entry shows:

```
http://<FQDN of ServiceDesk>/servicedesk/controller?docommand=renderradform&!key=esd_org019_frm_contact_list&isportalintegratedmode=true&USR=joe.bloggs%40gmail.com&_dc=1365665987887&redirecturl=controller%3Fdocommand%3Drenderbody%26%21key%3DESD_ORG019_FRM_CONTACT_LIST%26isportalintegratedmode%3Dtrue&sso_token=3NxsXYORMPp32SwL8ftVUCMH2QdWLH82&ONERROR=%2Fweb%2Fjsp%2Fapps%2Fportal-integration-error.jsp&itype=login&slicetoken=NW51O%242aRo%2C_Zz%2476P_9DTtnFmz6%28bhk&AUTOFORWARDURL=controller%3Fdocommand%3Drenderbody%26%21key%3DESD_ORG019_FRM_CONTACT_LIST%26isportalintegratedmode%3Dtrue&LOGINPAGE=https%3A%2F%2F<FQDN of Web Portal>>%2Fweb%2F4732cf01-82c3-4bc5-b6c9-552253e672cf%2Fapplication-setup&appid=1&!uid=1&!redownloadToken=7.0.3.1.1363611301.0&userlocale=en_US&!datechanged=2012-10-26%2019:00:25.08
```

From reading through the forums and other sites it looks like we should be use to use HAPROXY to redirect the traffic to https, but try as I might I cant get it to work.

This is our HAPROXY configuration:

```
global

    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend http-openfire
    bind *:7070
    default_backend openfire

backend openfire
    balance     roundrobin
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:7070 check
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:7070 check

frontend http-uapi
    bind *:7080
    default_backend uapi

backend uapi
    balance     roundrobin
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:7080 check
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:7080 check

frontend http-sec
    bind *:8080
        default_backend sec

backend sec
     balance     roundrobin
     server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:8080 check
     server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:8080 check

frontend http-wall
    bind *:9080
    default_backend wall

backend wall
    balance     roundrobin
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:9080 check
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:9080 check

frontend http-xmpp
    bind *:9090
    default_backend xmpp

backend xmpp
    balance     roundrobin
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:9090 check
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:9090 check

frontend http-aim
    bind *:10080
    default_backend aim

backend aim
    balance     roundrobin
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:10080 check
    server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:10080 check

frontend http-servicedesk
    bind *:8081
        default_backend servicedesk

backend servicedesk
     balance     roundrobin
     server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:8081 check
     server  <serverName> <IPv4 Address>:8081 check

listen stats :1936
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
    stats auth haproxy:<Password>
```

I have tried following the articles listed posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227544/haproxy-redirecting-http-to-https-ssl and http://parsnips.net/haproxy-http-to-https-redirect/ but that hasn't made any difference.

Am I on the right track with this or are we trying to achieve the impossible?, I'm hoping I'm just being an idiot and one of you good people can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you want to redirect all traffic that comes in on HTTP to HTTPS? You can do this quite easily when using HTTP mode in your front-end configuration.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in this thread:

[Apache SSL reverse proxy breaks Liferay Authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/452768/apache-ssl-reverse-proxy-breaks-liferay-authentication)

if you want to "fix" Liferay hardcoding http.